# cacls or icacls when denies permission to any folder makes sub folders still accessible.Any work around?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-prompt, windows-10-universal

*if I code:*

> **icacls "c:\users\%username%\desktop\folder" /deny:F %username%**

The above just deny full control to my folder on the desktop but all other folders inside it are accessible

*Like if I run this code*

> **"c:\users\%username%\desktop\folder\subfolder"**

The above code opens the subfolder even when the parent directory was denied all permissions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6ase.jpg"

---

And same with the subfolders under the subfolder of the parent directory.

(I've tried this)This works for the subfolders inside the parent directory, but not for the subfolders inside the subfolders of the parent directory:

> **icacls "c:\users\%username%\desktop\folder\*" /deny:F %username%**

---

I was wishing if there was some way to make all the subfolders and the subfolders inside and if any further, all inherit the permission of the root directory without actually manually assigning permission one by one

Comment: All users have transverse rights. So they can go to a folder they have permission for even if the parent doesn't allow access

Comment: but the parent directory's permission can be inherited by the subfolders to make them unaccessible too.Is it possible that all the subfolders and subfolders inside them, all inherit the permission granted or denied to the parent directory?

Comment: Type `icacls /?` for help.

Comment: I already did that and cannot find my answer there

Comment: `/t` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Gave me this Error when i used /t earlier:  
**c:\users\satya\desktop\folder\\*: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 1 files**

Comment: That's because the command has already worked. You no longer have permission to it. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I want to make an inaccessible folder all way down to all the subfolders.Is there a way to first deny permission to all subfolders then the parent folder?